# Adding assocation to CSV import from form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I want to add the `current_user.id` to each field of a CSV import, on import.

I have the CSV files importing successfully but when I try the following:

model:

```
def self.import(file)
  CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
    product_hash = row.to_hash
    product = Product.find_or_create_by!(sku: product_hash['sku'])
    product.update_attributes!(product_hash)
  end
end
```

controller:

```
  def create
    user = current_user
    Product.import(params[:product][:file], user_id: user.id)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to '/', notice: 'Products successfully imported.' }
    end
  end
```

form:

```
<%= form_for @product, url: product_upload_create_path do |f| %>
  <%= f.file_field :file  %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

(also tried adding hidden field for user)

error:

> ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)):

Since I can't call (or, from what I have read, is a bad idea) the current_user in the model.  How else would I be able to append the current_user.id onto each CSV import row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model is a fine place, if your actions are that concise (for longer preprocessing your might choose to use a service instead, but for a only a few lines, the model is fine).

While you can't get access to the current_user in the model (its a helper action available to the views and controller because it's session dependent) you are almost there with passing it to the model, which is perfectly acceptable.

Assuming that you're uploading the file directly (not possible with certain hosted solutions where you aren't allowed to accept file uploads), then your method will work, if you change it to allow both the file name and the user object as well.

I would change the model method to:

```
def self.import(file:, user_id:)
  CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
    product_hash = row.to_hash.merge(user: user_id)
    product = Product.find_or_create_by!(sku: product_hash['sku'])
    product.update_attributes!(product_hash)
  end
end
```

And change the implementation to

```
Product.import(file: params[:product][:file], user_id: user.id)
```

FYI, the notation of `def method_name(param:, param_2:)` means that both arguments are required.  If you needed only one to be required you can do `def method_name(param:, param_2:nil)` which makes the second argument optional

Comment: Anyone coming across this... `product_hash = row.to_hash.merge(user_id: user_id` is the one change i had to make